# Convert logic formula into CNF

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, conjunctive-normal-form

I'm trying to convert **¬(P∧ ¬R)∨(R∧Q)** into conjunctive normal form by using logical rules, but I'm stuck. Can you help me?

Comment: Stuck, where, exactly?  Successful or not, please show what you have tried, what you do or don't understand, and exactly where you have trouble?  (Hint: there are just two steps)

Comment: I used DeMorgan's Law: (¬P ∨ R)∨(R∧Q). Then I tried to rewrite ∨ using ¬ and ∧. For example A ∨ B = ¬ (¬ A ∧ ¬ B). So, I got ¬(¬(¬P ∨ R) ∧ ¬(R ∧Q)).

Comment: Then, ¬((P ∧ ¬R) ∧(¬R ∨ ¬Q)). I don't know what to do further. I think I make this more complicated than it actually is.

Comment: Yes, you have.  Look again at $\neg P\lor R\lor (R\land Q)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used DeMorgan's Law: $(¬P ∨ R)∨(R∧Q)$.

Okay, but $\vee$ is associative, so the bracketing of the first disjunct is optional.

> Then I tried to rewrite ∨ using ¬ and ∧. For example $A ∨ B = ¬ (¬ A ∧ ¬ B)$. So, I got $¬(¬(¬P ∨ R) ∧ ¬(R ∧Q))$.

No.  Go back a step and look again.

> I used DeMorgan's Law: $\lnot P\lor \underbrace{R\lor (R\land Q)}$.

Comment: I can use the distributive law: ¬P∨ R∨R ∧ R∨Q which is the same thing as ¬P∨R ∧ R∨Q. Is that the final answer?

Comment: (Sigh),  use Absorption  $\rm R\vee (R\wedge Q)\equiv R$